# GEOS Topology Exception While Using geopandas.dissolve

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, geopandas, shapely, geos

When I am using dissolve function from `Geopandas` I am getting the following error:

```
shapely.errors.GEOSException: Topology Exception: side location conflict at ...
```

I have checked the validity using both `is_valid` of `Geopandas` and `explain_validity` of `shapely` both are unable to find any invalid geometries.

Comment: In my experience, geos 3.12.1 solves quite some cases like that. Are you using that version already? If you already do, please provide a minimum code and data (e.g. as wkt in the code) sample that reproduces your problem.